# Function scope in JavaScript. Different objects same result

Tags: javascript, scope

My question is based on the following scenario.

```
var test = (function(){

    var SlideManager = !function(){
        this.Sequencer = {
            getSequence : function()...
        }
        return this;
    }()

    var LayerManager = !function(){
        this.Sequencer = {
            getSequence : function()...
        }
    }()

    var module = {};
    module.foo = function(){}
    return module;
})()
```

As an explanation, the test object has two helper objects in its scope: SlideManager & LayerManager. These two handle different actions for the entities slide && layer. Each entity has its own fixed position in the DOM, position which should be retrieved through the `Sequencer` helper object.

Please note that every Manager should have its own `Sequencer` and I would expect that to be true in the provided example.

However it seems that there is a problem with my understanding of js scopes because both Managers have the same `Sequencer` (The one from Layer Manager).

Should I expect something like this or am I doing something wrong somewhere else in the code.

Thank you!

Comment: "test" isn't an object. It's a boolean constant (`true` or `false`, depending on what that anonymous function returns). It'd probably be better to post the actual code you're using.

Comment: @Pointy: ditto for SlideManager & LayerManager.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes I agree - the code as posted doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Pointy OK I should explicitly state that the code sample is extracted from an existing working environment and I omitted some lines of code in order to show the exact problem. However I added some dummy lines in the example so that test is now an object :)

Comment: @Ionut: And does the code as you've posted it work, *except* for the issue you're having?  Cause it looks like it still has the problem Pointy and Scott were mentioning.

Comment: @ScottHunter The `...` existent at the end of the example were replaced with some dummy code and a `return` so that everyone can make sense of the context.

Comment: It's still the case that that code, as posted, does **not** initialize "test" to be an object.

Comment: @cHao The managers have multiple roles and there are a few other things done by this script and the `test` object. The problem are the `Sequencer` object for those two `Manager`s which don't work properly.

Comment: @Ionut: What two `Manager`s?  All i see are two booleans.  (Whatever the two IIFEs return, you then say "not that", which gives you a boolean.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expound upon what Scott Hunter said...

Just auto executing the functions (function() {})()  Does not give them a new scope.  For that you are wanting the "new" keyword.

So:

```
    var SlideManager = function(){
            this.Sequencer = {
                getSequence : function()...
            }
            return this;
        };

        var LayerManager = function(){
            this.Sequencer = {
                getSequence : function()...
            }
        };

var slideManagerInstance = new SlideManage();
var layerManagerInstance = new LayerManager();
```

Might be more what you are looking for... also why are you "!" banging the auto executed functions return before assigning... that will give you a true/false boolean?

Comment: `!` was my mistake. I apologize. Thanks for the `new` insight :)

Answer (score -1):

`this` in both Managers isn't local to that function, and thus is the SAME in both, which is why they have the same Sqeuencer.